# For a commutative ring $R$, the set of functions $f:R\rightarrow R$ is a comm. ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $F=F(R,R)$ be the set of
>   functions $f:R\rightarrow R$. Prove that $F$ is a commutative ring.

I want to show that $(F,+)$ is an abelian group. The easy parts of this proof are showing that there exists a multiplicative identity and that this ring is associative.

Associativity: Let $f,g,h\in F$. Then $[(f+g)+h](x)=(f+g)(x)+h(x)=f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=f(x)+(g+h)(x)=[f+(g+h)](x)$.

The identity element is $I$ such that $I(x)=0$ for all $x\in R$. Then $I+f=f+I=f$ for any $f\in F$. Since $0\in R,$ then $I:R\rightarrow R$ and $I\in F$.

What I'm unsure about is my proof for these two group axioms:

Inverses: Let $f\in F$. Then $f(x)\in R$ for all $x\in R$. Since $R$ is closed on additive inverses then $-f(x)\in R$. Thus, $-f:R\rightarrow R$ and $-f\in F$.

Closure: Let $f, g\in F$. Then, for any $x\in R$ we know $f(x),g(x)\in R$. Since $R$ is closed on addition, then $f(x)+g(x)=(f+g)(x)\in R$ so $(f+g):R\rightarrow R$ and $f+g \in F$.

- Are these valid proofs of addition inverses and closure?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose that the operation on $F$ are defined pointwise, so the neutral element for $(F,+)$ is the function $f(x)=0$, not $f(x)=x$. And you have also to prove that the producto is associative.

Comment: Oh, of course. I will make that edit. Thanks

Comment: Made the edit. Do associativity and identity look correct now?

Comment: Yes, I've post an answer for the other properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ring is a structure with two operations $(F,\oplus,\odot)$ such that:

1) $(F,\oplus)$ is a commutative group

2) $(F,\odot)$ is a monoid

3) The product $\odot$ is distributive over the addition $\oplus$.

I suppose that  the operations in the ring of functions are defined pointwise as:
$(f\oplus g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$

$(f \odot g)(x)= f(x)\cdot g(x)$

where $+$ and $\cdot$ are the sum and product in $R$ and $F$ is closed for the two operations simply because $R$ is closed for $+$ and $\cdot$.

If so, it is easy to prove that $(F,\oplus)$ is a commutative group, since it ereditates the properties of the sum $+$ in $(R,+)$ (that is a commutative group) and has as neutral element the function $f(x)=0$ and the opposite of $f(x)$ is $-f(x)$, as noted in OP.

For the product: We can see the function $I(x)=1$ is the neutral element  since $(I \odot f)(x)=I(x)\cdot f(x)$ and associativity is ereditated from $R$. (Note that we have not to prove the existence if an inverse, a property that can be proved only if $R$ is a field).

Finally we have to prove distributivity, i.e.

$
f\odot(g \oplus h)=f\odot g \oplus f\odot h 
$

And also this property is an easy consequence of the same property in $R$.

Comment: It's interesting: for some reason we never talked about checking distributivity in class even though it's in the textbook

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Definition for the definition of a ring.

Comment: By "ereditates," I think you mean "inherits." :)

Comment: YES! Sorry for my bad englisn.